# How to swap the roll and pitch of a quaternion

Tags: rotations, quaternions, angle

I'm writing code that receives quaternion values that are used to rotate a $3$D model. To display the model with the correct orientation, though, I'll need to swap the roll and pitch (rotation about the $x$ and $y$ axes). Since I can't change the code that produces the input quaternion, is it possible to swap the roll and pitch of a quaternion? I would like to do this without converting the quaternion to Euler angles to avoid issues if pitch is $90$ degrees.

In MATLAB, I converted various Euler angles to quaternions and then swapped the roll and pitch components of the Euler angles and converted that to quaternions. It's not obvious to me how to convert the original quaternion to the swapped version.

Comment: What have you tried? Did you compare examples of input quaternion with desired quaternion to find how to convert one into the other?

Comment: @Somos see Q update

Comment: Okay. Please include a few of those examples in your question. It could help to answer your question.

Comment: If you want someone to give useful advice that applies to your actual problem and not to some similar but different problem that they imagine you might have, it would pay for you to be very, very, **very** explicit about exactly how you want to do your roll, pitch, and yaw and how they have been done differently by the code you can't change. Even with the restriction that the $z$ axis is the yaw axis, there are literally dozens of ways to define pitch, roll, and yaw angles mathematically. In fact, are you absolutely sure that what you did in MATLAB was what you wanted to do? How do you know?

Comment: Even if you avoid conversions to and from Euler angles, there is probably no solution for the case where pitch is $90$ degrees, because when the model is pointing straight up it also has some angle of rotation around the world $z$ axis, and there is no way to tell how much of that rotation was due to roll and how much was due to yaw.

Answer (score 1):

Let $q=a+bi+cj+dk\in \mathbb H$ be a quaternion and let us denote its imaginary part as a vector in $\mathbb R^3$:
$$\left( \begin{matrix} b \\ c \\ d\end{matrix}\right) \in \mathbb R^3.$$

Then, we can apply the [rotation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix):

$${\displaystyle {\begin{alignedat}{1}R_{x}(\theta )&={\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&\cos \theta &-\sin \theta \\[3pt]0&\sin \theta &\cos \theta \\[3pt]\end{pmatrix},}\\[6pt]R_{y}(\theta )&={\begin{pmatrix}\cos \theta &0&\sin \theta \\[3pt]0&1&0\\[3pt]-\sin \theta &0&\cos \theta \\\end{pmatrix},}\\[6pt]R_{z}(\theta )&={\begin{pmatrix}\cos \theta &-\sin \theta &0\\[3pt]\sin \theta &\cos \theta &0\\[3pt]0&0&1\\\end{pmatrix},}\end{alignedat}}}$$

so that any rotation of angles $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ in the $z$, $y$, $x$ directions respectively, can be expressed as the following product, which will give you a new vector:

$$R_{z}(\alpha )\,R_{y}(\beta )\,R_{x}(\gamma )\left( \begin{matrix} b \\ c \\ d\end{matrix}\right)= \left( \begin{matrix} \hat b \\ \hat c \\ \hat d\end{matrix}\right).$$

Then, your rotated quaternion will be $\hat q = a + \hat b i + \hat c j + \hat d k$.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** As David K points out in the comments, there is an inherent well-definedness issue when pitch is $\pm90^\circ$. This manifests in my method when $I_i^2+I_j^2=0$. I address this case a bit at the end.

---

Let $q$ be our (normalized) quaternion and let $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ be yaw, pitch, and roll. In terms of an airplane, I am assuming that $i$ gives the current heading, $j$ is in the direction of the left wing, and $k$ is perpendicular to these pointing out of the top.

The pitch is exactly the angle that the new heading $I = qi\bar q$ makes with the original $ij$-plane, and the yaw is the angle that the projection of $I$ onto this plane makes with the original heading $i$. This means that we can write
$$
  \cos\beta = \sqrt{I_i^2 + I_j^2},\quad \sin\beta = I_k,
$$$$
  \cos\alpha = \frac{I_i}{\sqrt{I_i^2+I_j^2}},\quad \sin\alpha = \frac{I_j}{\sqrt{I_i^2+I_j^2}}.
$$
Here $I_i$ means the $i$-component of $I$, and likewise for $I_j, I_k$.

Now consider that the yaw, pitch, roll quaternions $Y, P, R$. We have $q = RPY$ and want $q' = RYP$. The yaw and pitch have the form
$$
  Y = \cos\alpha/2 + k\sin\alpha/2,\quad
  P = \cos\beta/2 + Yj\bar Y\sin\beta/2.
$$
We compute
$$
  YP
    = PY + [Y, P]
    = PY + \sin\frac\alpha2\sin\frac\beta2\,[k, Yj\bar Y]
    = PY - 2\sin\frac\alpha2\sin\frac\beta2\,Yi\bar Y
$$$$
  \implies
  q'
    = q - 2\sin\frac\alpha2\sin\frac\beta2\,RYi\bar Y
    = q - 2\sin\frac\alpha2\sin\frac\beta2\,q'\bar Pi\bar Y
$$$$
  \implies
  q' = q(1 + 2\sin\frac\alpha2\sin\frac\beta2\,\bar Pi\bar Y)^{-1}.
$$
Assuming $Y, P, R$ to be units, so are $q$ and $q'$ and so the last factor on the RHS is a unit as well. Thus
$$
  q' = qs,\quad s = 1 - 2\sin\frac\alpha2\sin\frac\beta2\,YiP.
$$

For the moment write $C_\alpha, C_\beta, S_\alpha, S_\beta$ for  the half-angle cosines and sines. It's easy to see that $P$ takes the form
$$
  P = C_\beta + S_\beta(-i\sin\alpha + j\cos\alpha).
$$
So now we compute
$$\begin{aligned}
  YiP
    &= (C_\alpha + S_\alpha k)i[C_\beta + S_\beta(-i\sin\alpha + j\cos\alpha)]
\\
    &= (C_\alpha i + S_\alpha j)[C_\beta + S_\beta(-i\sin\alpha + j\cos\alpha)]
\\
    &= C_\beta(C_\alpha i + S_\alpha j) + S_\beta[C_\alpha\cos\alpha + S_\alpha\sin\alpha]k + S_\beta[C_\alpha\sin\alpha - S_\alpha\cos\alpha]
\\
    &= C_\beta C_\alpha i + C_\beta S_\alpha j + S_\beta C_\alpha k - S_\beta S_\alpha
\end{aligned}$$
and thus
$$\begin{aligned}
  2S_\alpha S_\beta YiP
    &= i\frac12\sin\alpha\sin\beta + jS_\alpha^2\sin\beta + kS_\beta^2\sin\alpha - 2S_\beta^2S_\alpha^2
\\
    &= \frac12\Bigl[i\sin\alpha\sin\beta + j\left(1 - \cos\alpha\right)\sin\beta + k\left(1 - \cos\beta\right)\sin\alpha - \left(1 - \cos\beta\right)\left(1 - \cos\alpha\right)\Bigr].
\end{aligned}$$
Finally, we write
$$
  2s = 3 + I_i - \sqrt{I_i^2 + I_j^2} - \frac{I_i}{\sqrt{I_i^2+I_j^2}} - i\frac{I_jI_k}{\sqrt{I_i^2+I_j^2}} - jI_k\left[1 - \frac{I_i}{\sqrt{I_i^2+I_j^2}}\right] + kI_j\left[1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{I_i^2+I_j^2}}\right].
$$

---

When $\beta = \pm90^\circ$ this doesn't work; in fact we can't distinguish between roll and yaw. What we can do in this case is define the *turn* $\delta$ as the angle between $j$ and $J = qj\bar q$:
$$
  \cos\delta = J_j,\quad \sin\delta = J_k.
$$
Then we have to decide how much of the turn is due to yaw and how much is due to roll. The two most natural cases are

- **All roll:** In this case we can take $Y = 1$ whence $q = q'$.
- **All pitch:** In this case we can take $R = 1$ and $\alpha = \delta$. Reusing our work from before,
  $$
    q' = qs,\quad 2s = 3 - J_j \mp J_ki \mp (1-J_j)j - J_kk
  $$
  where $\pm$ corresponds to $\beta = \pm90^\circ$, which can be distinguished via $qi\bar q = \pm k$.